# Recurrance Event Display

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

I am facing some problems when I create a recurrance event in the calendar. I used the calendar on "Quick Launch" and created a recurrance event for 3 days and the event name is displayed only once for 3 calendar days. Then I navigated to may home page and used that calendar as a webpart. Now when I look at the recurrance event, the event name is displayed just thrice but it covers 3 calendar days. I am using the same view for both of them. I am attaching the images for clarification.

This is the image on the calendar webpart
[image: Image1]

This is the image from when I use the "Calendar" from quick launch
[image: Image2]

Now my query is I want the event name to be displayed the same way as it is displayed in the webpart. Is it the default behaviour or did I miss something.

Note: I developed the solution on a standalone machine and there was no problem regarding the display of reccurance events. But when I save it as .wsp file and deploy it on a farm I am facing the above mentioned issue. Is there something that I need to do? Please suggest

Comment: Hey folks, any suggestions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply [February 2011 SharePoint Foundation 2010 hotfix package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2479788).

Quote:

> Consider the following scenario You create a recurring event in a
>   calendar list in a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site. You save the site
>   that includes the site contents as a template. You create a new site
>   by using that template.
>
> In this scenario, the calendar list does not display the recurring
>   event in the new site.